# Equivalent of and.callThrough() in jest-preset-angular

Tags: angular, jest-preset-angular, angular-test

Reading through [this link](https://www.xfive.co/blog/testing-angular-faster-jest/) i got to know that the equivalent of

`and.callFake` is `mockImplementation` and

`and.returnValue` is `mockReturnValue`.

Similarly is there an equivalent of `and.callThrough()` in jest-preset-angular?

Answer (score 31):

This question may be really old, but tripped me up recently.

Jest, by **default**, will call the underlying function in a similar manner to `.and.callThrough()`.

This is the **opposite** behaviour of Jasmine, which blocks the call to the underlying function unless `.and.callThrough()` is specified.

To block the underlying call in Jest, call the `mockImplementation()` function.

Comment: Does that mean that, wherever we used `.and.callThrough()` before, we can remove it and it calls the actual function?

Answer (score -3):

Most of these Jasmine2-related methods are not available anymore. See the Jest documentation for more information on e. g. how to call through spied methods.

---

### Outdated Answer

Jest [by default](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testrunner-string) will use Jasmine2 as test runner, and therefore you can use most (if not all) Jasmine methods.

All of the ones you requested are in Jest available, `and.callFake`, as well as `and.returnValue` and `and.callThrough`.

Comment: Since Jest 27 this seems to be not true anymore as deduced from here: https://githubmemory.com/repo/nrwl/nx/issues/6063